# Set jsTree Node to "Undetermined" State

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I'm using [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) to show a tree with checkboxes. Each level of nodes is loaded on-demand using the `json_data` plugin.

If a node's descendent is checked, then that node should be in an "undetermined state" (like ACME and USA).

[image: Checked Descendent in jsTree]

The problem is, the tree starts out collapsed. ACME looks `unchecked` but *should* be `undetermined`. When I finally expand to a checked node, jsTree realizes the ancestors should be `undetermined`.

[image: Expanding to checked node fixes the problem]

So I need to be able to put a checkbox in the `undetermined` state without loading its children.

With `jsTree` you can pre-check a box by adding the `jstree-checked` class to the `<li>`. I tried adding the `jstree-undetermined` class, but it doesn't work. It just puts them in a checked state.

Here's my code:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    plugins: ["json_data", "checkbox"],
    json_data: {
        ajax: {
            url: '/api/group/node',
            success: function (groups) {
                var nodes = [];
                for (var i=0; i<groups.length; i++) {
                    var group = groups[i];

                    var cssClass = "";
                    if(group.isSelected)
                        cssClass = "jstree-checked";
                    else if(group.isDecendantSelected)
                        cssClass = "jstree-undetermined";

                    nodes.push({
                        data: group.name,
                        attr: { 'class': cssClass }
                    });
                }
                return nodes;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

### My Question

**How do I set a node to the `undetermined` state?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and the solution I found was this one:

```
var tree = $("#tree").jstree({
    plugins: ["json_data", "checkbox"],
    json_data: {
        ajax: {
            url: '/api/group/node',
            success: function(groups) {
                var nodes = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
                    var group = groups[i];
                    var checkedState = "false";
                    if (group.isSelected)
                        checkedState = "true";
                    else if (group.isDecendantSelected)
                        checkedState = "undetermined";
                    nodes.push({
                        data: group.name,
                        attr: { 'checkedNode': checkedState }
                    });
                }
                return nodes;
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('li[checkedNode="undetermined"]', tree).each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('jstree-unchecked').removeClass('jstree-checked').addClass('jstree-undetermined');
                });
                $('li[checkedNode="true"]', tree).each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('jstree-unchecked').removeClass('jstree-undetermined').addClass('jstree-checked');
                });
                $('li[checkedNode="false"]', tree).each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('jstree-checked').removeClass('jstree-undetermined').addClass('jstree-unchecked');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: So the `jstree-undetermined` class has to be set after the success callback runs - ie. complete.

Comment: Yes, I didn't found any other way.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this changed in the meanwhile...

But now (version 3.0.0) the really simple solution works:

```js
{
    id          : "string" // will be autogenerated if omitted
    text        : "string" // node text
    icon        : "string" // string for custom
    state       : {
        opened    : boolean  // is the node open
        disabled  : boolean  // is the node disabled
        selected  : boolean  // is the node selected
        undetermined  : boolean  // is the node undetermined <<==== HERE: JUST SET THIS
    },
    children    : []  // array of strings or objects
    li_attr     : {}  // attributes for the generated LI node
    a_attr      : {}  // attributes for the generated A node
}
```

Learned directly from the source code at: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/6507d5d71272bc754eb1d198e4a0317725d771af/src/jstree.checkbox.js#L318

Comment: WOW! The docs need to updated to show this! I just wasted an hour or so trying to figure out hacks to accomplish this!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, and I found an additional trick which makes life a little better, but it requires a code change in jstree.js.  Looks like an oversight:

Look at the **get_undetermined** function, and scan for the keyword *break*.  That *break* should be a **continue**.

If you make that one change, then all you need to do is provide the state (for the main object and its children), and jstree will automatically take care of cascading upwards for undetermined state.  It was bailing out early from the scripting and failing to catch all the undetermined nodes properly, requiring the above ugly workarounds for styling and such.

Here's my config (no special attrs or complete() function required) using AJAX:

```
var tree = $('#jstree').jstree({
    "core": {
        "themes": {
            "variant": "large"
        },
        'data': {
            'url': function (node) {
                return "{{API}}/" + node.id + "?product_id={{Product.ID}}"
            },
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'GET',
            'success': function (data) {
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    data = rootStub
                }
                return {
                    'id': data.id,
                    'text': data.text,
                    'children': data.children,
                    'state': data.state,
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "checkbox": {
        // "keep_selected_style": false,
        "three_state": false,
        "cascade": "undetermined"                        
    },
    "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
});
```