# JStree: How to set state of AJAX-loaded root nodes to undetermined

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, treeview, jstree

I'm using [jstree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162186/set-jstree-node-to-undetermined-state) v3.0.2 to display a tree of nodes with three-state checkboxes (checked, unchecked, undetermined), which I load in JSON-format through an AJAX call.
Only the root nodes are loaded, the children are loaded on demand when the user expands a node. Therefore, we don't know yet which children of a node are (un)checked, but the root node has to be checked, unchecked or undetermined depending on the underlying children.

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162186/set-jstree-node-to-undetermined-state), which hopefully makes my problem more understandeable, but that one seemingly relates to an older version and doesn't account for lazy-loading of nodes. Also, the [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850086/408656) which suggests using the "undetermined" state doesn't seem to work.

The JSON which is initially loaded (for the topmost root nodes) looks like this:

```
[{
    "id":"100",
    "parent":"#", // Indicates this is a topmost root node
    "text":"test1",
    "children":false, // Wether or not the node has children
    "state":{
        "selected":true, // Node is selected
        "partial_selection":false // Node state >should be< undetermined
    }
},{
    "id":"101",
    "parent":"#",
    "text":"test2",
    "children":true,
    "state":{
        "selected":true,
        "partial_selection":true
    }
},{
    "id":"102",
    "parent":"#",
    "text":"test3",
    "children":true,
    "state":{
        "selected":false
    }
}]
```

Has anyone found out a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

OK I managed to solve this issue. Apparently jstree *does* accept the 'undetermined'-state (when using the latest version of the library, in my case 3.0.2), as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162186/set-jstree-node-to-undetermined-state/23850086#23850086) already suggested, but it only works when the 'selected'-state is omitted (which makes sense).
Refer to [the issue I filed](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/757#issuecomment-48645235) on Github for some more details.